# Command Line cURL to PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am having trouble converting command line cURL to php cURL.  I have read the other links on this topic, and am still stuck, and would appreciate any help.

I am trying to automatically put contact info from a web form into an online CRM.

API info:  http://karmacrm.zendesk.com/entries/23648323-Contacts

My Code:

```
$header = array('contact[first_name]=aaaaaaa','API-KEY: XXXXXXXXX');
$pageurl = "https://app.karmacrm.com/api/v2/contacts.json";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $pageurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'mXXXX@gmail.com:7iNXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); // -i
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE); // -v
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMEREQUEST, "POST"); //-X
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, FALSE); // --data-binary, -d
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

The Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Connection: keep-alive 
Status: 401 
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.11 
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1 
Cache-Control: no-cache, private 
X-Request-Id: 8d9397e1c2d43580db7XXXXXXXXXXXX 
X-Runtime: 0.004153 
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 03:14:27 GMT 
X-Rack-Cache: miss 
Server: nginx/1.2.3 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.11 (mod_rails/mod_rack)

{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}1
```

Thanks for any help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the POST values as HTTP headers, which is not the same.

Use this:

```
$data = array('contact[first_name]' => 'aaaaaaa', 'api_token' => 'XXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

And remove the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option.

Just as a side note: the linked API description says nothing about sending login details to the API - there's only the API token (which is usual for APIs).

Comment: Thank you so much, this was 100% correct, and fixed everything.  Sorry I am amateur, Thanks again..

Answer (score -1):

example :

```
$url = 'link_to_api';
$params = array('username'=>'admin','password'=>'passw0rd');


    public function call_ws_post($url = '', $params = array()){
    $service_url = $url;
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    $curl_post_data = $params;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($curl_response === false) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additional info: ' . var_export($info));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    $decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
    if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
        die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
    }
    return $decoded;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think this will help compared to the current approach?

Comment: I think @eshepard set params as header post did not accurately